# Criar um enumerador no QML pelo C++

Tags: c++, qt, enums, qml

Estou tentando utilizar um enumerador que foi criado no C++ e estou utilizando o próprio site do QT 5.6 para me orientar, [Data Type Conversion Between QML and C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html). Porém ao compilar eu recebe a seguinte exceção do compilador:

**error: undefined reference to `TypeSexClass::staticMetaObject'**

[image: Erro na compilação no Qt 5.6]

### Enum

```
#include <QObject>
class TypeSexClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(TypeSex)
public:
    enum TypeSex{
        NONE, MEN, WOMAN};
    TypeSex typesex() const;
};
```

## Main

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtQml>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    TypeSexClass typesexclass();

    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<TypeSexClass>("teste.typesex", 1, 0, "TypeSexClass","It`s not do create");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

## O resolvido

## Enum

```
#ifndef TYPESEX_H
#define TYPESEX_H

#include <QObject>

class TypeSexClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:    
    enum TypeSex{
        NONE, MAN, WOMAN};
    Q_ENUM(TypeSex)
};

#endif // TYPESEX_H
```

## Main

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtQml>
#include "typesex.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<TypeSexClass>("teste.typesex", 1, 0, "TypeSex","It's not instantiable. It's a enumeration");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

## QML

```
Window {
    id: window1
    title: "Redi"
    visible: true
    visibility : "Maximized"
    Button {
            id: button1
            x: 457
            width: 100
            height: 50
            text: qsTr("Gerar")
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 33
            onClicked: {                
                console.log(TypeSex.MAN)
                console.log(TypeSex.WOMAN)
                console.log(TypeSex.NONE)
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde o Qt 5.5 você deve usar uma nova macro chamada [`Q_ENUM`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_ENUM) **imediatamente após** a definição da enumeração. No seu caso:

```
enum TypeSex{NONE, MEN, WOMAN};
Q_ENUM(TypeSex)
```

Observe que não precisa mais fazer nenhum registro manualmente no meta class, basta usar a macro. Bem mais fácil! :)

Mais informações [nesta postagem](https://woboq.com/blog/q_enum.html) (em inglês).

> P.S.: Preciosismo bobo, mas use plural ou singular em tudo na sua
>   definição da enumeração. *Men* está no plural, e *Woman* no singular
>   (use *Men* e *Women*, ou *Man* e *Woman* - que parece ser o mais
>   apropriado para a enumeração que vc está fazendo).

Comment: Eu alterei como vc sugeriu e ocorreu um outro erro
**error: 'friend' used outside of class
     friend Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR const QMetaObject *qt_getEnumMetaObject(ENUM) Q_DECL_NOEXCEPT { return &staticMetaObject; } \**

Comment: Por acaso a enumeração (e, consequentemente, a chamada de `Q_ENUM`) não está num .cpp, está? Deveria estar em um .h.

Comment: está em um header (.h)

Comment: Eu vi que vc editou a pergunta. Bom, não devia ter editado, porque um usuário futuro perde a referência do problema original. Depois, por favor, volte pra versão anterior. De todas as formas, eu vi que vc agora declarou a enum fora do escopo de uma classe herdada de QObject (e que não usa mais a macro Q_OBJECT). Mas eu creio que a enum *precisa* ser feita nesse escopo e a macro é necessária. Ou seja, deixe o seu código com estava antes, só remova a macro Q_ENUMS e adicione a Q_ENUM.

Comment: Certo, eu editei pois o stack nao deixa vc colocar as alterações e sugere que se edite a pergunta, mas consigo sim voltar. Eu vou testar dessa forma que vc me passou.

Comment: Bom era isso mesmo que vc falou, eu precisei declarar o meu enumerador dentro de um classe com o macro do **Q_OBJECT** e usei o **Q_ENUM**
Thks